# Inverse image of connected set

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

We are given a continuous surjective function $f: X \to Y$ with a property that the the set $\{f^{-1}(y)  \}$ is connected for each $y \in Y$. Then the given statement is supposed to be false.
$$For\ every\ connected \ subset\ A \subset Y,\  f^{-1}(A) \ is\ connected$$

Can someone please give me an example to prove the given statement is false.

Comment: Hmm. What about the identity map $\mathbb{R}_{\delta} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{R}_{\delta}$ is endowed with the discrete topology?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer In the discrete topology every open set with 2 or more elements is necessarily not connected, am I wrong?

Comment: @MateusFigueiredo Yes, but that would be what we're looking for, right? Any connected subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that isn't just a point will have an infinite discrete pre-image.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer that's a valid example. thank you.

Comment: So you may answer the question. Good and simple example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the identity map $\mathbb{R}_{\delta} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{R}_{\delta}$ is endowed with the discrete topology. Then any connected subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that isn't just a point will have infinite discrete pre-image.